# Why does TinyMCE require an API key?

Tags: tinymce

Basically the title. Taken a look at their website, however I don't understand what the point of the TinyCloud is or why I need to provide an API key even for a free version. I initally thought it was somewhere data was saved, however it appears that the save feature submits a post request to your domain, so I am not sure why their cloud exists.

Answer (score 0):

Probably marketing and to give out free trials of paid plugins.

If you don't want to sign up for the free plan, you could try another CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tinymce